# CallBack error: Callback error updating hist-graph.figure

Tags: python, pandas, callback, dashboard

I'm doing a dashboard in Python and whenever I execute the code i get de error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "D:\Estudos\Maps\Aula1\Starter\index.py", line 84, in update_histdf_intermediate = df_intermediate[df_intermediate["GROSS SQUARE FEET"] <= size_limit]TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

can't understand why the error.

My Callback:

```
@app.callback(Output('hist-graph','figure'),
             [Input('location-dropdown','value'),
             Input('slider-square-size','value'),
             Input('dropdown-color','value')])
def update_hist (location, square_size, color_map):
    if location is None:
       df_intermediate = df_data.copy()
    else: 
        df_intermediate = df_data[df_data["BOROUGH"] == location] if location != 0 else df_data.copy
        #size_limit = slider_size[square_size] if square_size is not None else df_data["GROSS SQUARE FEET"].max()
        size_limit = float(slider_size[square_size]) if square_size is not None else df_data["GROSS SQUARE FEET"].max()
        df_intermediate = df_intermediate[df_intermediate["GROSS SQUARE FEET"] <= size_limit]
        #df_intermediate = df_intermediate["GROSS SQUARE FEET"] <= size_limit

    hist_fig = px.histogram(df_intermediate, x = color_map,opacity = 0.75)
    hist_layout = go.Layout(
        margin=go.layout.Margin(l=10, r=0,t=0,b=50),
        showlegend=False,
        template="plotly_dark",
        paper_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)")

    hist_fig.layout = hist_layout
    return hist_fig
```

the _histograph.py:

```
from dash import dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.update_layout(template = "plotly_dark", paper_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)")


hist = dbc.Row([
        dcc.Graph(id="hist-graph",figure=fig)
    ], style={"height": "20vh"})
```

could help me understand?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.Missed closing the "()" of the copy method

```
df_intermediate = df_data[df_data["BOROUGH"] == location] if location != 0 else df_data.copy()
```

I read the code several times and didn't see